# ABP IHttpClientProxy in non-IHost-ed environment

Tags: abp

Using **ABP Framework v3.2.1**, we are wanting to use the ABP `IHttpClientProxy` **dynamic proxy classes** in application environments other than .NET Core hosts *(E.g, AWS Lambda function, Xamarin client app)* - where the only ABP modules required are those that `IHttpClientProxy` depends on.

Firstly, is this supported?

Secondly, what would be the process to load a single "entry" module that's not a hosted service?

Going through the source, I can only find the `IServiceCollection.AddApplication` extension methods - there doesn't appear to be the same for "AddModule"